# Calculate total amount in my database but it doesn't working

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
<?php

global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT rate FROM schedule_reg");
foreach ($result as $row) {
$result = 0;
$result = $result + $row->rate;
echo "TOTAL AMOUNT : RM" .$result;
}

?>
```

I want to calculate all total amount in my database but it doesn't working. Anyone can help me...

Comment: Everytime you run the loop, it reset $result to 0, leave the `$result = 0` line before the loop

Comment: Also, *doesn't work* is a vague term that does not describe anything. Please add more details to your question, what is happening? is there any error? what is the difference between the actual output and your expected output?

Comment: why you not just use this: `SELECT SUM(rate) FROM schedule_reg` it will give you the exact amount, then you can format it like you want.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have: like it was described by the @catcon was that you use `$result` inside the loop, so each time it resets to `0` every single loop. so you have to move that out of the loop:
**INITIAL**

```
<?php

global $wpdb;
$rows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT rate FROM schedule_reg");//change to rows
foreach ($rows as $row) {
   $result = 0;
   $result = $result + $row->rate;
   echo "TOTAL AMOUNT : RM" .$result;
}

?>
```

**AFTER**

```
<?php

global $wpdb;
$rows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT rate FROM schedule_reg");//change to rows
$result = 0;
foreach ($rows as $row) {
   $result = $result + $row->rate;
}
echo "TOTAL AMOUNT : RM" .$result;
?>
```

**OR THIS:**

```
    <?php
    
    global $wpdb;
    $rows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT rate FROM schedule_reg");//change to rows
    $result = 0;
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
       $result += $row->rate;
    }
    echo "TOTAL AMOUNT : RM" .$result;
    ?>
```

I propose another approach to this problem, so you can use `DB` to calculate this for you, using the slight different SQL query:
`SELECT SUM(rate) FROM schedule_reg` like this:

```
    <?php
    
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT SUM(rate) FROM schedule_reg"); // here you get total amount
    echo "TOTAL AMOUNT : RM" . $result[0]->result_value;
    ?>
```

This should helps you.